# MySQL: SELECT to local variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following mysql stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_INTO_WORKDAY(IN deviceName VARCHAR(16),
                                     IN cardUID VARCHAR(14)) 
BEGIN
    SET @projectId = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM PROJECT WHERE DEVICEID =
          (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM DEVICE WHERE NAME = deviceName)
             ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1);
    SET @workerId = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM WORKER WHERE CARDNUMBER = cardUID);
    SELECT @workerId;
    
    SET @id = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM WORKDAY
                   WHERE WORKERID = @workerId
                     AND PROJECTID = @projectId
                     AND STOPTIME IS NULL
                     AND STARTTIME IS NOT NULL);
    IF (@id >= 0)
        THEN
            UPDATE WORKDAY SET STOPTIME = now() WHERE ID = @id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO WORKDAY (WORKERID, PROJECTID, STARTTIME)
            VALUES (@workerId, @projectId, now());
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the procedure once, I get the result:

```
mysql> CALL INSERT_INTO_WORKDAY("Pepper_C1-1A6318", "045D91B22C5E80");
+-----------+
| @workerId |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)
```

From second run, is not working anymore:

```
mysql> CALL INSERT_INTO_WORKDAY("Pepper_C1-1A6318", "045D91B22C5E80");
+-----------+
| @workerId |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'WORKERID' cannot be null
```

I did try to isolate and run the procedure with only this two lines of code:

```
    SET @workerId = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM WORKER WHERE CARDNUMBER = cardUID);
    SELECT @workerId;
```

And it behaves just like above, but if I try to run `SELECT MIN(ID) FROM WORKER WHERE CARDNUMBER = "045D91B22C5E80";` alone, works without problems.
The `@projectId` variable behaves normal everytime I call the stored procedure.

Can someone help me to find a solution?
Thank you!

My setup:

```
mihai:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

```
mysql> describe WORKER;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FIRSTNAME  | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| LASTNAME   | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CARDNUMBER | varchar(14) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| POSITIONID | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM WORKER;
+----+-------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| ID | FIRSTNAME   | LASTNAME  | CARDNUMBER     | POSITIONID |
+----+-------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|  1 | Ionut Mihai | Popescu   | 045D91B22C5E80 |          1 |
|  2 | Ilie        | Zbagan    | 040D7FB22C5E81 |          2 |
|  3 | Ilie        | Ungureanu | 043FA8B22C5E80 |          1 |
|  4 | Adrian      | Tehanciuc | 04D894B22C5E80 |          2 |
|  5 | Ioan        | Bitoanca  | 0405C6B22C5E81 |          2 |
+----+-------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `WORKER`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `WORKER` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FIRSTNAME` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `LASTNAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CARDNUMBER` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `POSITIONID` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `POSITIONID` (`POSITIONID`),
  CONSTRAINT `WORKER_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`POSITIONID`) REFERENCES `POSITION` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: I gather there can be multiple rows with the same WORKERID and PROJECTID ?

Comment: Please provide `CREATE TABLE` and enough rows `INSERTed` to exhibit the problem with those 2 lines.

Comment: Edited the question, providing dump code for WORKER table and all the data inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my declared local variable `id`.
After I changed her name, everything worked just fine.

My previous answer was:

I don't know what the problem was, but I did found a solution.
I wrote:

```
    SELECT MIN(ID) FROM WORKER WHERE CARDNUMBER = cardUID INTO @workerId;
    SELECT @workerId;
```

instead of

```
    SET @workerId = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM WORKER WHERE CARDNUMBER = cardUID);
    SELECT @workerId;
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug.  Please file a bug at bugs.mysql.com and post the link to it here.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames ! Here is the link: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102144&thanks=sub